# How to get weighted average while skipping rows with a string on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to get weighted average of values in column A with weights in column B. Problem is that column A might have string values and I want to skip these rows from calculation. Unlike =AVERAGEIF, function =AVERAGE.WEIGHTED does not have this implemented.

How do I do it? And how would I do it if column B could also have strings (for future proofing)?

Comment: so if we might skip things, we should no longer count on weights summing to 1, so we would need to divide by the sum of the actually used weights?

Comment: Sum of weights is not 1. Its any float number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(FILTER(A:A,ISNUMBER(A:A)),FILTER(B:B,ISNUMBER(A:A)))`

`=SUM(FILTER(A:A*B:B / sum(FILTER(B:B,ISNUMBER(A:A))),ISNUMBER(A:A)))`

`=SUM(FILTER(A:A*B:B / (sum(B:B) - SUMIF(A:A,"><", B:B)),ISNUMBER(A:A)))`

case both columns contain strings, add 1 more condition for each formula:

`=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(FILTER(A:A,ISNUMBER(A:A),ISNUMBER(B:B)),FILTER(B:B,ISNUMBER(A:A), ISNUMBER(B:B)))`

Comment: I tried first formula with values 200, "string", 1000, 100 in column A and values "string", 5, 2, 1 in column B. It gives me wrong answer of 387.5. It should only refer to last two rows ((1000, 2), (100, 1)) and give answer of 700.

Comment: I did not see from the Q both columns could be a string, `=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(FILTER(A:A,ISNUMBER(A:A),ISNUMBER(B:B)),FILTER(B:B,ISNUMBER(A:A), ISNUMBER(B:B)))`

Answer (score 0):

So let us suppose our numbers (we hope) sit in A2:A4 and the weights are in B2:B4. In C2, place

```
=if(and(ISNUMBER(A2),isnumber(B2)),A2,"")
```

and drag that down to C4 to keep only actual numbers for which we have weights.

Similarly in D2 (and drag to D4), use

```
=if(and(ISNUMBER(A2),isnumber(B2)),B2,"")
```

and in E2 (and drag to E4) we need

```
=if(and(ISNUMBER(C2),isnumber(D2)),C2*D2,"")
```

then our weighted average will be:

```
=iferror(sum(E2:E4)/sum(D2:D4))
```

you can hide the working columns or place them in the middle of nowhere if you wish.

Comment: Field of the weighted average sits in another sheet

Comment: That should still work, just you need to prepend a name and exclamation mark. My work columns could be wherever you want. But honestly, what @max makhrov posted is a lot more compact, and I would do that.